# Keycloak: Way to manage default client roles assigned to a user in a realm

Tags: terraform, keycloak

In Keycloak, for every realm there are [default roles](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_default_roles) which are assigned to a new user. This also assigns Client Default Roles. I want to update the built in client *account* default roles and maintain it as part of config as code.

I did not find any REST API for managing Client Default Roles for a realm. For example using Terraform [keycloak_default_roles](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mrparkers/keycloak/latest/docs/resources/default_roles) Resource, I can control the realm global roles, but I did not found a way to control the Client Default Roles. Can someone help here?

Update:
What I am trying to achieve is, we want to enable edit username option, but only for admins and users should not be able to change either username or email from their profile.

Comment: Does this help: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mrparkers/keycloak/latest/docs/resources/role#example-usage-client-role?

Comment: @MarkoE I do not want to modify the roles in the client itself but rather remove some roles from built in clients from defaultRoles which will be assigned to the new user. I did not see any option in this resource to do that

Comment: @Sirish do you want to remove all the defaultRoles from the client or really just some of them?

Comment: @dreamcrash I want to remove only manage-account default client role for account client using config-as-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This REST API can control default role for new user in realm.

Get default roles list

```
GET {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{realm}/roles-by-id/{default-roles-realmId}/composites
```

Add custom role into default role

```
POST {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{realm}/roles-by-id/{default-roles-realmId}/composites
```

Delete custom role from default role

```
DELETE {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{realm}/roles-by-id/{default-roles-realmId}/composites
```

This demo, I will shows this steps

1 Get master token
See [this step at first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

2 Get role list

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/test-realm/roles
```

[image]

[image]

3 Get default role for test-realm
Using 2's default-roles-test-realm ID

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/test-realm/roles-by-id/f3af5fc6-2829-4330-be45-a9fbc39c4b02/composites
```

4 Add custom role in test-realm

[image]

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/test-realm/roles
```

In body

```
{
    "name": "realm_custom_default_role",
    "description": ""
}
```

the status should be return **201 Created**

5 Add it to default-role for new user

[image]

In Body, this get step 2 after step 4

```
[
    {
        "id": "736b0d92-60b9-40ee-9d1f-dd13bc631975",
        "name": "realm_custom_default_role",
        "description": "",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": false,
        "containerId": "fb2137dd-68b0-473a-aab1-b0b5305b429a"
    }
]
```

6 Get Default role list again to confirm step 5 is added

[image]

7 Get new user role to check default role applied
new custom role added if add new user
[image]

8 Delete the custom role from default role

[image]
in body,

```
[
    {
        "id": "736b0d92-60b9-40ee-9d1f-dd13bc631975",
        "name": "realm_custom_default_role",
        "description": "",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": false,
        "containerId": "fb2137dd-68b0-473a-aab1-b0b5305b429a"
    }
]
```

the return status should be **204 No Content**

Comment: Can this also be someway in either terraform or pulumi during config deployment

Comment: I have no experience to use Terraform or Pulumi. I have no idea how to use those calls.