# Disable built-in account client for a realm in Keycloak using Terraform

Tags: terraform, keycloak

Keycloak by default enables few built in clients when a new realm is created. I want to disable a built-in client for every realm created using Terraform.

How can I do it only using Terraform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak: Way to manage default client roles assigned to a user in a realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581803/keycloak-way-to-manage-default-client-roles-assigned-to-a-user-in-a-realm)

Comment: @MarkoE other question was specific to removing some roles from a client. This question is to completely disable a client with Terraform and not using REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the default Terraform keycloak provider does not expose any resources for configuring built-in clients, one option is to use null_resource as described in another stackoverflow question [Terraform REST API calls with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197781/terraform-rest-api-calls-with-curl)

Answer (score 0):

v4.0.0 of the Keycloak Terraform provider added the `import` argument to the `keycloak_openid_client` resource, which allows you to automatically import clients that Keycloak creates by default without needed to run `terraform import`.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mrparkers/keycloak/latest/docs/resources/openid_client#import