# How to avoid manually copying jwt token in authorization header in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, jwt, header, authorization

I am learning Node.js but got stuck here. I watched a tutorial and they taught to copy JWT token in authorization header in postman every time. I want to avoid this. I know I can do this using cookies or localstorage but I want to do this in headers only.

Can anyone help me out in this.

HOW TO ADD TOKEN IN AUTHORIZATION HEADER WITHOUT MANUALLY COPYING IT IN POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

Using [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) library

```
axios.get(
       url = YOUR_URL,
       data = {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                }
            }
        );
```

[CRUD examples](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro)

This is my demo code.
Get the access token and get query with access token.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const config = require('./config.json');

const getAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token',
            data = {
                'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret': config.CLIENT_SECRET,
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
             }
        );
        console.log(resp.data);
        return resp.data.access_token;
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const getQuery = async (access_token, query) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(
            url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels?query='+ query,
            data = {
                headers: {
                    'Client-Id': config.CLIENT_ID,
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                }
             }
        );
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

(async () => {
    const access_token = await getAccessToken();
    console.log(access_token);
    await getQuery(access_token, 'fruit');
})()
```

This is configuration file

```
{
    "CLIENT_ID" : "thnrxxxxxxxxxxxxxqltb",
    "CLIENT_SECRET" : "8yxyfxxxxxxxxxxxxxf2ztt"
}
```

result from terminal

[image]

Just reference.
This method not necessary to copy an access token every time in Postman.
[first step-using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

Comment: is there any other method that excludes another module functioning?

Comment: What is meaning "excludes another module functioning"?

Comment: like in this axios is involved

Comment: node.js built-in request is now deprecated. So external module is common. [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js)