# Searching for Keycloak user via attribute - searchForUserByUserAttribute - how is it fast?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Not experienced with keycloak, and haven't been able to find answers after a hefty google. Quick question - I have a custom attribute, `userOrg`, which is an uuid. It maps to a user organisation that  lives outside of keycloak, in another database and contains the full details about the organisation (e.g. name, location).

I'm reviewing some code and see a previous team mate has written custom keycloak api extension, `findUsersByAttribute`, which uses
`session.users().searchForUserByUserAttribute`
to locate all user with a specified `userOrg`.

I'm guessing this would actually be a full table walk?

Or am I wrong and keycloak *somehow* provides indexing over attributes to allow fast lookup?

Next question - does keycloak provide a way of indexing over attributes/idea of user organisations.  Or should that logic be outside of keycloak (e.g. in another database have a mapping of users and orgs).

Is it spelled out anywhere in the docs?

Thanks

Comment: There is a Keycloak issue opened for this, as a heads up for future viewers of this... https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/12671... and it has an open PR for it that isn't merged as of this comment, https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/22285.

Answer (score 1):

You can search a user by user attribute via [Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html).

Endpoint. It depends on your Keycloak version

```
{keycloak URL}/auth/admin/realms/{my-realm}/users/?q=userOrg:{uuid}
or
{keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{my-realm}/users/?q=userOrg:{uuid}
```

In, `Get users Returns a stream of users, filtered according to query parameters.` section

[image]

[image]

I demoed it in local Keycloak v18.0.2 and [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)

1 I made 3 users by UI
[image]

2 Each users has own userOrg
[image]
[image]
[image]

3 [Get master token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

4 search user by UUID

`http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/users/?q=userOrg:3db51e81-7569-4a05-aaf3-91058450c63e`

Keycloak response matched user by attribute search API

[image]

I tested with 10K users. it take 10~12 msec by my laptop.
[image]

Here is my user created program by python

```
import json
import admin
import random
import uuid

admin = admin.Admin()
token = admin.get_master_token()

first_names = [ \
    "AARON","ADAM","ALAN","ALBERT","ANDREW","ANTHONY" \
    ,"ANTONIO","ARTHUR","BENJAMIN","BILLY","BOBBY" \
    ,"BRANDON","BRIAN","BRUCE","CARL","CARLOS" \
    ,"CHARLES","CHRIS","CHRISTOPHER","CLARENCE","CRAIG" \
    ,"DANIEL","DAVID","DENNIS","DONALD","DOUGLAS" \
    ,"EARL","EDWARD","ERIC","ERNEST","EUGENE" \
    ,"FRANK","FRED","GARY","GEORGE","GERALD" \
    ,"GREGORY","HAROLD","HARRY","HENRY","HOWARD" \
    ,"JACK","JAMES","JASON","JEFFREY","JEREMY" \
    ,"JERRY","JESSE","JIMMY","JOE","JOHN" \
    ,"JOHNNY","JONATHAN","JOSE","JOSEPH","JOSHUA" \
    ,"JUAN","JUSTIN","KEITH","KENNETH","KEVIN" \
    ,"LARRY","LAWRENCE","LOUIS","MARK","MARTIN" \
    ,"MATTHEW","MICHAEL","NICHOLAS","PATRICK","PAUL" \
    ,"PETER","PHILIP","PHILLIP","RALPH","RANDY" \
    ,"RAYMOND","RICHARD","ROBERT","ROGER","RONALD" \
    ,"ROY","RUSSELL","RYAN","SAMUEL","SCOTT" \
    ,"SEAN","SHAWN","STEPHEN","STEVE","STEVEN" \
    ,"TERRY","THOMAS","TIMOTHY","TODD","VICTOR" \
    ,"WALTER","WAYNE","WILLIAM","WILLIE"]

last_names = [ \
    "Adams","Allen","Alvarez","Anderson","Bailey",\
    "Baker","Bennet","Brooks","Brown","Campbell",\
    "Carter","Castillo","Chavez","Clark","Collins",\
    "Cook","Cooper","Cox","Cruz","Davis",\
    "Diaz","Edwards","Evans","Flores","Foster",\
    "Garcia","Gomez","Gonzales","Gray","Green",\
    "Gutierrez","Hall","Harris","Hernandez","Hill",\
    "Howard","Hughes","Jackson","James","Jimenez",\
    "Johnson","Jones","Kelly","Kim","King"\
    "Lee","Lewis","Long","Lopez","Martin",\
    "Martinez","Mendoza","Miller","Mitchell","Moore",\
    "Morales","Morgan","Morris","Murphy","Myers",\
    "Nelson","Nguyen","Ortiz","Parker","Patel"\
    "Perez","Peterson","Phillips","Price","Ramirez",\
    "Ramos","Reed","Reyes","Richardson","Rivera",\
    "Roberts","Robinson","Rodriguez","Rogers","Ross",\
    "Ruiz","Sanchez","Sanders","Scott","Smith",\
    "Stewart","Taylor","Thomas","Thompson","Torres",\
    "Turner","Walker","Ward","Watson","White",\
    "Williams","Wilson","Wood","Wright","Young",]

user_list = []
index = 1
user_data = {}
access_item = {}
user_list = []
max_user_count = 10000
size_first_name = len(first_names)
size_last_name = len(last_names)
for index in range(1,max_user_count+1):
    first_name_index = random.randint(0, size_first_name)
    last_name_index = random.randint(0, size_last_name)
    user_data['enabled'] = True
    user_data['groups'] = []
    user_data['emailVerified'] = ''
    user_data['firstName'] = first_names[first_name_index-1].capitalize()
    user_data['lastName'] = last_names[last_name_index-1]
    user_data['username'] = 'user'+str(index)
    user_data['email'] = 'user'+str(index)+'@test.com' 
    user_data['attributes'] = { 'userOrg' : [ str(uuid.uuid4())]}
    user_list.append(user_data)
    print(json.dumps(user_data))
    user_data = {}

# add user if not exist
for user in user_list:
    if (not admin.is_user_exist(token, 'test', user['username'])):
        admin.add_user(token, user, 'test')
        print('Add User', user['username'])
```

Get token code, name should be `admin.py`

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError

import requests
import ast
import json

class Admin:
    # Keycloak master realm URL
    url = 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token'

    # Keycloak master credential
    params = {
        'client_id': 'admin-cli',
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username' : 'admin',
        'password': 'admin'
    }
 
    def get_master_token(self):
        try:
            response = requests.post(self.url, self.params, verify=False).content.decode('utf-8')
        except HTTPError as http_err:
            print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
            print('Keycloak container is not running, Please check your docker container!')
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            return ast.literal_eval(response)['access_token']

            

    def add_user(self, token, user, realm_name):
        url ='http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'+realm_name+'/users'
        headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ str(token)
        }
        params = {
            'username': user['username'],
            'enabled': True,
            'totp': False,
            'emailVerified': True,
            'firstName': user['firstName'],
            'lastName': user['lastName'],
            'email': user['email'],
            'attributes': user['attributes'],
            'disableableCredentialTypes': [],
            'requiredActions': [],
            'notBefore': 0,
            'access': {
                'manageGroupMembership': True,
                'view': True,
                'mapRoles': True,
                'impersonate': True,
                'manage': True
            },
            'realmRoles': [ realm_name ]    
        }
        x = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)
        return x.content

    def is_user_exist(self, token, realm_name, user_name):
        url ='http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'+realm_name+'/users/?username='+user_name.replace(" ", "%20")
        headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ str(token)
        }
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            response.raise_for_status()
        except HTTPError as http_err:
            print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
        else:
            if len(response.content) == 2: # []
                return False
            if (json.loads(response.text)[0]['username'] == user_name.lower()):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think you missed the my question. I know you can filter by attribute. What I am trying to understand is the speed/efficieny of it. Is it a full table scan or is  it indexed?

Comment: I think it is full table scan by DB SQL predicate search. It is not takes a time to search. How many user you handle and how fast you expected? Here is source code of [user attribute search](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/model/jpa/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/jpa/JpaUserProvider.java#L907)

Comment: I tested 10K users and get the response time. It took 10~12 msec for search.