# Is it possible to add the client_id to the userinfo?

Tags: keycloak

I’ve been trying to add the client id to the userinfo, so I can retrieve it when consuming the /userinfo endpoint.

I’ve tried a few mappers and managed to add a lot of useful information in it, but not the client_id itself.

I can’t rely on customization. Everything must be done with native configuration. Also I am using KeyCloak version 18.0.2.

My last attempt was to a User Property and look for the serviceAccountClientId from the class User Model, but it didn’t workout.

Comment: you can add `specific client id` into user's attribute in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75530965/how-to-add-programmed-custom-field-to-keycloak-user/75532971#75532971)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **client_id** from the ID token **Audience "aud"** field.