# How to distinguish if user is logged in from a Provider or from a user in Keycloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak, provider

I am integrating Keycloak into a React Application.
I have successfully added Google Providers in Keycloak.
Now the user can either log in with Keycloak user's credentials or from Login with Google.
After login how to distinguish if a user is with React or with a Provider?
And how to acquire the ID of that user so for certain activities to store that ID in the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GET User's detail REST API detect which identity provider's user.

[Get representation of the user](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource)

[image]

The `federatedIdentities` fields shows it

[image]

[here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html#_federatedidentityrepresentation)

[image]

Demo this user login via google

You needs a master token in Posman.

#1 Get master token at Posman.

Detail instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

#2 Get user list

```
GET http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/users
```

#3 Get google user

```
GET http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/users/{google-user-uuid}
```

[image]

#4 Get regular user

```
GET http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/users/{user-uuid}
```

This user logged via regular Keycloak
[image]