# Problem in assigning roles to user while creating it with Post HTTP request

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I can successfully create user by calling the following path in Postman software:

```
http://{KEYCLOAK_IP}/auth/admin/realms/{REALM_NAME}/users
```

The body content that I send is like following:

```
{
    "enabled":true,
    "username":"Reza",
    "email":"reza@sampleMailServer1.com",
    "firstName":"Reza",
    "lastName":"Azad",
    "credentials": [
        {
        "type":"password",
        "value":"123",
        "temporary":false
    }
    ]
}
```

Now, let’s assume that we have a client, which is named *browserApp* and this client has a role, which is named *borwserAppRoleUser*. Also, the realm has a role, which is name *realmRoleUser*.
In order to include abovementioned roles in the body content of the HTTP request I tried the following structure:

```
{
"enabled":true,
    "username":"Reza",
    "email":"reza@sampleMailServer1.com",
    "firstName":"Reza",
    "lastName":"Azad",
    "credentials": [
        {
        "type":"password",
        "value":"123",
        "temporary":false
    }
    ],
    "role": [
       {
           "id": "borwserAppRoleUser",
           "name": "test",
           "description": "${role_create-client}",
           "composite": false,
           "clientRole": true,
           "containerId": "browserApp"
       },
        {
            "id":"realmRoleUser",
            "composite":false,
            "clientRole":false
        }

    ]

}
```

Sending the above body content results in 400 bad request response. The errors contains this message:

> Unrecognized field "role" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation), not marked as ignorable

Also, I am sure that the rest of the role object is not correct.

I searched for examples online, but I could not find any sample regarding the role assignment. Can any body please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API not supports realm & client roles by single JSON data.
It only support by Add Realm with JSON import

The simple JSON format is like this but it needs extra data.
[This is working example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/src/test/resources/testrealm.json) for Import Realm JSON data

```
{
    "id": "test",
    "realm": "test",
    "users": [
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "username": "Reza",
            "email": "reza@sampleMailServer1.com",
            "firstName": "Reza",
            "lastName": "Azad",
            "credentials": [
                {
                    "type": "password",
                    "value": "123",
                    "temporary": false
                }
            ],
            "realmRoles": [
                "user"
            ],
            "clientRoles": {
                "borwserAppRoleUser": [
                    "test"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "scopeMappings": [
        {
            "client": "borwserAppRoleUser",
            "roles": [
                "test"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "client": {
        "borwserAppRoleUser": [
            {
                "name": "test",
                "description": "${role_create-client}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "roles": {
        "realm": [
            {
                "name": "user",
                "description": "Have User privileges"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you want to assign user's realm role and client role, use separate API call.

#1 Assign user's realm role

```
POST {KEYCLOAK-IP}/auth/admin/realms/{REALM-NAME}/users/{USER-UUID}/role-mappings/realm
```

In Body of POST

```
[
    {
        "id": {REALM ROLE UUID},
        "name": {ROLE NAME},
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": false,
        "containerId": {REALM NAME}
    }
]
```

1.1 Get master token - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

1.2 Get User UUID
[image]

1.3 Get Realm role UUID and name
[image]

1.4 POST realm role into user
[image]

#2 Assign user's client role

```
POST {KEYCLOAK-IP}/auth/admin/realms/{REALM-NAME}/users/{USER-UUID}/role-mappings/clients/{CLIENT-UUID}
```

In Body of POST

```
[
    {
        "id": {CLIENT ROLE ID},
        "name": {ROLE NAME},
        "description": "${role_create-client}",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": true,
        "containerId": {CLIENT-UUID}
    }
]
```

2.1 Get master token
2.2 Get user UUID - same 1.2
2.2 Get Client UUID
[image]

2.3 Get Client role UUID & name
[image]

2.4 POST client role into user
[image]

Finally confirm both assigned roles by this API

```
GET {KEYCLOAK-IP}/auth/admin/realms/{REALM-NAME}/users/{USER-UUID}/role-mappings
```

[image]