# Keycloak JWT to contain user real and client role

Tags: jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using Keycloak version 20.0.1 (also tried on 19.0.0).
I have a realm configured and under the Client Scopes -> realm roles -> Mappers I have added the `realm_access.roles` mapping.

For some reasons that I don't understand, the JWT token that I get as a response doesn't contain the Realm Roles (I have also assigned a realm role to the user that it's used for testing).

The response that I get is:

```
{
  "exp": 1669579902,
  "iat": 1669579602,
  "auth_time": 1669577841,
  "jti": "9dfe2638-a9f8-4094-8691-7a1423b629f7",
  "iss": "https://auth.xxxx.com/realms/xxxx.com",
  "sub": "6fe1b9b9-5ddd-478d-9b38-bd11698295cf",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "spring-client",
  "nonce": "d14b168b-3c77-489b-85dd-192dba533624",
  "session_state": "55d938d4-42e7-4c2b-9038-f808c917c366",
  "acr": "0",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "*"
  ],
  "scope": "openid email profile roles",
  "sid": "55d938d4-42e7-4c2b-9038-f808c917c366",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "first last",
  "preferred_username": "user@email.com",
  "given_name": "first",
  "family_name": "last",
  "email": "user@email.com"
}
```

How should I add the `roles` into the JWT response returned by Keycloak?

[image]

I have tried to configure the Client Scopes -> ream roles -> Mappers and I was expecting to receive in the JWT response the `roles` field.

Answer (score 1):

In the JWT of Keycloak, two roles information.

It is not represented user's assigned role. Just assigned client role are included but realm's roles is possible list of realm.

If you want to get all of assigned role, have to call `role mapping` of user API (see #3.1)

I decoded JWT by [jwo.io](https://jwt.io/) after get access token by Postman with Keycloak v 19.0.2

### #1 realm roles list - It is not assigned realm role list, it is possible role list

User JWT(access token), get `grant_type = password`

```
{
  "exp": 1669599866,
  "iat": 1669596266,
  "jti": "ad4e3b51-b23e-4abb-aba6-0099bb5213cf",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/example",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "fae8bf9b-2209-4f01-ab32-629e029941ba",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "spring-client",
  "session_state": "8debdcfa-4252-4a27-8190-2a4981e6a795",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "admin",
      "default-roles-example",
      "uma_authorization",
      "user"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "spring-client": {
      "roles": [
        "client role2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "8debdcfa-4252-4a27-8190-2a4981e6a795",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "first last",
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "given_name": "first",
  "family_name": "last",
  "email": "user@test.com"
}
```

five realm's roles are possible realm's role not assigned user's roles
[image]

User just assigned three realm's roles
[image]

Client JWT(access token), get `grant_type = client_credentials`

```
{
  "exp": 1669597154,
  "iat": 1669593554,
  "jti": "ff6ae9db-7e05-4f9a-a538-0755a7f55125",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/example",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "9db11aa2-6862-4ebb-9ee6-b03b51d7814d",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "spring-client",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "default-roles-example",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "clientId": "spring-client",
  "clientHost": "172.19.0.1",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "service-account-spring-client",
  "clientAddress": "172.19.0.1"
}
```

Those are client's roles, it has three roles but not matched JWT's realm list
In the JWT (client access token), that list is possible realm list(not assigned client realm roles)

[image]

### #2 client role - It is assigned client list

```
GET {KEYCLOAK-IP}/auth/admin/realms/{REALM-NAME}/clients/{client-UUID}/roles
```

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/example/clients/1cb76d56-b96f-42a7-91c0-c201a7761e9e/roles
```

```
[
    {
        "id": "e5171eb5-976e-429f-914c-0d63d7b394fd",
        "name": "client role2",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": true,
        "containerId": "1cb76d56-b96f-42a7-91c0-c201a7761e9e"
    },
    {
        "id": "293c9c9c-bb76-4192-be09-ede769458394",
        "name": "uma_protection",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": true,
        "containerId": "1cb76d56-b96f-42a7-91c0-c201a7761e9e"
    },
    {
        "id": "e1441ceb-7ea8-436b-9a55-30999c6de744",
        "name": "client role1",
        "description": "",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": true,
        "containerId": "1cb76d56-b96f-42a7-91c0-c201a7761e9e"
    }
]
```

### #3 user's role list can get the separate API

3.1 all of user's role
GET {KEYCLOAK-IP}/auth/admin/realms/{REALM-NAME}/users/{USER-UUID}/role-mappings

UI:
[image]

It seems to block, UI not allow to assign directly a user into client role from UI. I use REST API call. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244798/problem-in-assigning-roles-to-user-while-creating-it-with-post-http-request/74250457#74250457)

[image]

Example, get user's roles:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/example/users/fae8bf9b-2209-4f01-ab32-629e029941ba/role-mappings
```

Response

```
{
    "realmMappings": [
        {
            "id": "c31bd5ce-e400-4546-b633-d4d5bde596d8",
            "name": "admin",
            "description": "Administrator privileges",
            "composite": false,
            "clientRole": false,
            "containerId": "e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439"
        },
        {
            "id": "d99f61be-bacd-438d-974d-06a006704a1e",
            "name": "default-roles-example",
            "description": "${role_default-roles}",
            "composite": true,
            "clientRole": false,
            "containerId": "e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439"
        },
        {
            "id": "8d250d6c-e249-4b63-b86f-390b4550b12e",
            "name": "user",
            "description": "User privileges",
            "composite": false,
            "clientRole": false,
            "containerId": "e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439"
        }
    ],
    "clientMappings": {
        "spring-client": {
            "id": "1cb76d56-b96f-42a7-91c0-c201a7761e9e",
            "client": "spring-client",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "id": "e5171eb5-976e-429f-914c-0d63d7b394fd",
                    "name": "client role2",
                    "composite": false,
                    "clientRole": true,
                    "containerId": "1cb76d56-b96f-42a7-91c0-c201a7761e9e"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see, how to set the role into client or user,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244798/problem-in-assigning-roles-to-user-while-creating-it-with-post-http-request/74250457#74250457)

Answer (score -1):

to get roles or anything in token we had protocol mappers in version 18.0 and earlier. for version 19 and above it is removed but **only from ui**
you can add protocol mapper by rest api

```
/POST  {keycloak_url}/admin/realms/demo/clients/<clientId>/protocol-mappers/models
```

authorization:Bearer token //should be admin token

```
{
"protocol":"openid-connect",
"config{
"multivalued":"true",
"id.token.claim":"true",
"access.token.claim":"true",
"userinfo.token.claim":"true",
"usermodel.realmRoleMapping.rolePrefix":"",
"claim.name":"realmRoles"
},
"name":"roleNameMapper",
"protocolMapper":"oidc-usermodel-realm-role-mapper"
}
```