# mod_auth_openidc: how do I get claims from the provider's access token?

Tags: apache, mod-auth-openidc

I've missed something very basic in how `mod_auth_openidc` works.

I'm using Keycloak, and if I do a curl request to get a token (in other words, I log in with a username and password), then I get back a JWT. Part of the JWT payload contains:

```
"openid-connect" : {
  "roles": ["role-1", "role-2", ..."role-n"]
}
```

`mod_auth_openidc` is presumably doing the same request, and getting back the same JWT. However, none of this is being passed on to my app. All I can see is the session Cookie (`mod_auth_openidc_session`), but there are no OIDC headers or env variables.

What have I missed - how do I persuade `mod_auth_openidc` to send the Keycloak roles (or anything else) on to the app?

Comment: you can some hits in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75508151/keycloak-assign-a-client-scope-to-user-with-a-specific-role/75513974#75513974) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593497/keycloak-jwt-to-contain-user-real-and-client-role/74595089#74595089)

Comment: @BenchVue - thanks, but I've already got the roles into the JWT, so `mod_auth_openidc` will also get the roles. The question is 'why is `mod_outh_openidc` not returning these roles to the app behind the  Apache reverse proxy?

Comment: Yes, Access Token only includes realms roles and resource roles. [Here](https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/test/test.c) is mod_auth_openidc token test example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was testing using the minimal PHP app [on the wiki](https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc/wiki). In my Apache config, I was allowing unauthorised access to this test page:

```
  <Location /oidctest.php>
    Require all granted
  </Location>
```

This doesn't work; `mod_auth_openidc` sees that no claims are required, and doesn't supply any. If I change the `require` to something more realistic:

```
Require claim "resource_access.openid-connect.roles:role-3"
```

then everything springs into life: the PHP test page shows lots of claims. With `require all granted`, nothing was passed: not even the `REMOTE_USER`, so the test page just showed "Hello,", rather than "Hello, [email address]".