# Keycloak API: Getting updated access token using refresh token returns 401

Tags: keycloak, http-status-code-401

I've been assigned to overhaul an app that relies on Keycloak. Currently, when a user logs into the app, their session only lasts for 5 minutes before their access token expires. In the JavaScript code, each function checks if there's an updated access token in the response and if so then stores it. That means if the user is just browsing around the app without making a request, then they'll be logged out. I'm wanting to fix it so that if there's user activity of any sort (even just moving the mouse or browsing through pages), then the access token can be updated.

All of the other requests work fine, and the login request returns a refresh token in its response. However, when I make a POST request to get a new access token using the refresh token, then I get a 401 error. I've tried making this request inside the app and also using Postman and Insomnia, and I always get a 401 error.

Here's the request I'm making:

- POST method
- URL: http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token
- Form:

  - client_id: admin-cli
  - grant_type: refresh_token
  - refresh_token: [refresh token here]
- Headers:

  - Content-Type: when using Insomnia, it's "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; in the app, it's "application/json"

I've read that a client_secret is required when the client is confidential. However, 'admin-cli' is not confidential and doesn't have a client secret set up. Also, I've checked in the Keycloak Admin UI that refresh tokens are enabled.

Thanks for any help, it's much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**: JWTs decoded

Here's the payloads of the access token and refresh token from BenchVue's answer:

**ACCESS TOKEN**

```
{
  "exp": 1707230290,
  "iat": 1707229990,
  "jti": "41833ad2-d6a3-45d6-9ac3-fd4793c749a5",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm",
  "sub": "f273bb9e-7a2a-49c3-b7f5-241efd4a4afd",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "114d3130-4502-4e63a448-9fc96e464879",
  "acr": "1",
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "114d3130-4502-4e63-a448-9fc96e464879",
  "email_verified": true,
  "preferred_username": "user1"
}
```

**REFRESH TOKEN**

```
{
  "exp": 1707231790,
  "iat": 1707229990,
  "jti": "ecfc896f-93a8-4aa3-a2f9-c323d91c66ef",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm",
  "aud": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm",
  "sub": "f273bb9e-7a2a-49c3-b7f5-241efd4a4afd",
  "typ": "Refresh",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "114d3130-4502-4e63-a448-9fc96e464879",
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "114d3130-4502-4e63-a448-9fc96e464879"
}
```

And here's the access and refresh token from company app:

**ACCESS TOKEN**

```
{
  "exp": 1707230135,
  "iat": 1707229835,
  "jti": "54942e59-4d25-4233-aefd-6c6c9a972c0a",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/[redacted]",
  "sub": "8dd3a5a5-b467-4d65-9b2b-95da87d8bb36",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "558057da-dd11-43e6-ab10-aa35aa4a7235",
  "acr": "1",
  "scope": "email profile",
  "sid": "558057da-dd11-43e6-ab10-aa35aa4a7235",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "[redacted]",
  "preferred_username": "[redacted]",
  "given_name": "[redacted]",
  "family_name": "[redacted]",
  "email": "[redacted]@test.com"
}
```

**REFRESH TOKEN**

```
{
  "exp": 1707231635,
  "iat": 1707229835,
  "jti": "8dc3d5c1-636a-4645-b653-070a267da710",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/[redacted]",
  "aud": "http://localhost:8080/realms/[redacted]",
  "sub": "8dd3a5a5-b467-4d65-9b2b-95da87d8bb36",
  "typ": "Refresh",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "558057da-dd11-43e6-ab10-aa35aa4a7235",
  "scope": "email profile",
  "sid": "558057da-dd11-43e6-ab10-aa35aa4a7235"
}
```

Comment: Which version of Keycloak using it? Can you attached the POSTMAN call screen, header, input body part and response body.

Comment: @BenchVue Updated with screenshots. Realm name redacted (don't want to expose the company I work for). The screenshots show the refresh token being pulled from the login request. I've also tried running the login post and manually copy-pasting the refresh token. Also shown is the config for the admin-cli client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Two cases

## Case 1 - Client authentication OFF

[image]

Will this setting can get new tokens
[image]

##### Step 1 get tokens

In `tests` tab

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", jsonData.access_token);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("refresh-token", jsonData.refresh_token);
```

[image]

Input Body with `x-www-form-urlencoded` format

```bash
client_id: 'admin-cli'
grant_type: 'password'
username: {user name}
password: {user password}
```

[image]

##### Step 2 get new tokens by refresh token

Input Body with `x-www-form-urlencoded` format

```bash
client_id: 'admin-cli
grant_type: 'password'
username: {user name}
password: {user password}
grant_type: 'refresh_token'
refresh_token: {{refresh-token}} <- Step 1's refresh-token
```

[image]

---

## Case 2 - Client authentication ON

[image]

This URL and body data will get new tokens

URL

```
POST ${keycloakUrl}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Input Body with `x-www-form-urlencoded` format

```bash
client_id: {id}
client_secret: {secret}
grant_type: 'refresh_token'
scope: {scope}
refresh_token: {previous refresh_token}
```

[image]

I will demo the whole process from user logging to get the `refresh token` by API in your local PC.

##### Requirement for Demo

Save as `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest  # Update to the latest Keycloak image
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true  # Enable HTTP if you're not using HTTPS
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

##### Run it

```bash
docker compose up
```

It will launch  Keycloak version 23.0.3

[image]

##### Setting Keycloak

`Step 1` Create 'my_realm'

`Step 2` Create 'my_client'

`Step 3` Add redirect URI 'http://localhost:3000/auth/callback'

`Step 4`  setting `my_client` configuration

`Step 5` copy Client Secret for demo(server.js)

`Step 6` create user1 and set password by '1234'

[image]

##### Demo code

Save as 'server.js'

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const session = require('express-session');

// TODO: Replace these with your actual configuration values
const clientId = 'my_client';
const clientSecret = 'MplDSOhQoiNwjjmA4w1YkBh5YteV8CJx';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/callback';
const realmName = 'my_realm';
const keycloakUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
const responseType = 'code'; 

// Express setup
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Set up the session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'top-secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }));

app.use(cors()); // Add CORS middleware

// Function to generate a code verifier for PKCE
function generateCodeVerifier() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '');
}

// Exchange Authorization Code For Tokens
async function exchangeAuthorizationCodeForTokens(authorizationCode, clientId, redirectUri, realmName, keycloakUrl) {
    
    const tokenEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

    const codeVerifier = generateCodeVerifier();
    const data = {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: 'MplDSOhQoiNwjjmA4w1YkBh5YteV8CJx',
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        code: authorizationCode,
        code_verifier: codeVerifier
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, new URLSearchParams(data), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            httpsAgent: new (require('https').Agent)({ rejectUnauthorized: false }), // Ignore self-signed certificate
        });

        console.log('Token exchange successful');
        console.log(response.data);
        return {
            access_token: response.data.access_token,
            refresh_token: response.data.refresh_token,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Token exchange failed:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        return false;
    }
}

// Get New Tokens by old  Refresh Token
async function getRefreshToken(clientId, clientSecret, refresh_token, realmName, keycloakUrl) {
    
    const tokenEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

    const codeVerifier = generateCodeVerifier();
    const data = {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        scope: 'openid email',
        refresh_token: refresh_token
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, new URLSearchParams(data), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            httpsAgent: new (require('https').Agent)({ rejectUnauthorized: false }), // Ignore self-signed certificate
        });

        console.log('Token refresh successful');
        console.log(response.data);
        return {
            access_token: response.data.access_token,
            refresh_token: response.data.refresh_token,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Token exchange failed:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        return false;
    }
}

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    // Construct the Keycloak login URL
    const keycloakLoginUrl = `${keycloakUrl}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=${encodeURIComponent(clientId)}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}&response_type=${encodeURIComponent(responseType)}&scope=openid`;

    // Redirect the user to the Keycloak login page
    res.redirect(keycloakLoginUrl);
});
app.get('/auth/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const authorizationCode = req.query.code;
    if (!authorizationCode) {
        return res.status(400).send('Authorization code is required');
    }

    // Exchange authorization code for tokens
    const tokens = await exchangeAuthorizationCodeForTokens(authorizationCode, clientId, redirectUri, realmName, keycloakUrl);
    
    if (tokens) {
        req.session.accessToken = tokens.access_token;
        req.session.refresh_token = tokens.refresh_token;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(`{'Access Token': ${tokens.access_token}, 'Refresh Token': ${tokens.refresh_token}}`, null, 4));
    } else {
        res.status(500).send('Failed to exchange authorization code for tokens');
    }
});


app.get('/refresh_token', async (req, res) => {
    const tokens = await getRefreshToken(clientId, clientSecret, req.session.refresh_token, realmName, keycloakUrl);
    
    if (tokens) {
        req.session.accessToken = tokens.access_token;
        req.session.refresh_token = tokens.refresh_token;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(`{'new Access Token': ${req.session.accessToken}, 'new Refresh Token': ${req.session.refresh_token}}`, null, 4));
    } else {
        res.status(500).send('Failed to exchange authorization code for tokens');
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

##### Install server dependencies

```
npm install express axios cripto cors express-session
```

##### run server.js

```
node server.js
```

#### login user1

Open Browser

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

[image]

After login, the will be displayed token in the Browser

[image]

##### Get new Tokens

```
http://localhost:3000/refresh_token
```

[image]

##### Get new Tokens by Postman

Copy the refresh_token from Browser to Postman
Then click the `Send` button, the other setting is to follow the top explain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I ran what you provided and it works as expected. However, it doesn't solve the issue I'm facing with my company's app.

Comment: My point is you need to send client_secret too.

Comment: I will test Direct Grant Access Only checked case.

Comment: @OldLavyGenes474, can you try case 1, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed steps. Now I know how to set up a Keycloak and NodeJS project using Docker which will surely come in handy. I went through both set up steps that you proposed, and they work as expected. However, I'm still facing the same issue with the company app. (Continued in next comment)

Comment: I've changed the settings through the admin UI console for the company app's Keycloak instance to exactly match the settings from both process 1 and 2 in your answer, and even still the request for getting a new access token returns 401. The settings, roles, client scopes, and other settings assigned to admin-cli all match, and still the company app returns 401 while the instance running through Docker returns 200.

Comment: In the request body, I've tried multiple variations, including the client_id, grant_type, client_secret, username, and password, and no matter what, it returns 401

Comment: I'll have to look and see if maybe the issue pertains to user role/permissions. UPDATE: User settings are exactly the same between the Docker instance and the company instance. Also checked Realm and Authentication settings, and they exactly match.

Comment: I checked all the clients, and in both the Docker project and company project, each has "Use refresh tokens" toggled.

Comment: Token has some information , like user role, can you see this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593497/keycloak-jwt-to-contain-user-real-and-client-role/74595089#74595089) and try to decode user rule.

Comment: I updated the post to include the decoded JWT's. Do the user roles have to be present in the token in order to get a refresh token?

Comment: UPDATE: I ran the following command in Powershell, and it returns a response:
$headers = @{
>>     "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>> }
>> $body = @{
>>     client_id = "admin-cli"
>>     grant_type = "refresh_token"
>>     refresh_token = "[token here]"
>> }
>>
>> $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:8080/realms/[realm]/protocol/openid-connect/token" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body

Comment: That means for some reason, the request is being rejected when run in Postman, Insomnia, or through code in the app.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct since you helped me out so much. The problem still exists, but luckily I've managed to narrow it down. The fact that the command runs on Powershell and keycloak is running in dev mode for the company app suggests there's some setting that needs to be changed in that regard.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep watch your 401 error. The access token have any user role, but it will not affect 401 error when get the refresh token for new access token. Good Luck to study. see you later.