# Users inherit client roles in keycloak?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, roles

In keycloak does the user inherit roles from the clients ?

If so, is this configurable ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user can assign client's role by UI of Keycloak or REST API.
User can get inherit roles from multiple clients.

It is configurable with combination clients roles.

I will demo assign a roles by UI
[image]

#1 Assigned four roles from three clients and default role.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#2 Get roles mapping for specific user by API

```
GET http://{keycloak-IP}/auth/admin/realms/{my-realm}/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings
```

Using post man and [master token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215).

[image]