# Keycloak - Using curl API to create a Keycloak client with the "view_users" role

Tags: api, curl, keycloak, admin

I would like to create a client on Keycloak with parameters defined when running the curl API.
Among the defined parameters I would like to add to the client the "view_users" role, which is found in the "Client Roles" entitled "realm-management".
I would like to reproduce this action with API curl :
[Adding the "view_users" role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIrt1.png)
[The role "view_users" is assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OjKf.png)

Currently, my API request to create my client looks like this:

```
curl --location --request POST "http://$ip:8180/auth/admin/realms/$realm/clients" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" \
    --data-raw '{
        "clientId": "test",
        "enabled": true,
        "consentRequired": false,
        "protocol": "openid-connect",
        "standardFlowEnabled": true,
        "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
        "directAccessGrantsEnabled": false,
        "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
        "authorizationServicesEnabled": true,
        "rootUrl": "http://localhost:8180/test"
    }'
```

There is probably a field missing in "data-raw" to assign the "view_users" role from the "realm-management" client to my test client.
Can you help me to find this field? Or can you suggest an alternative solution?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't set `view_users` role at the client creation time.

It can be assign after creation by separate API (client role mapping)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/users/$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_ID/role-mappings/clients/$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer $MASTER_TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[
    {
        "id":$VIEW_USER_ID,
        "name":"view-users",
        "description":"${role_view-users}",
        "composite":true,
        "clientRole":true,
        "containerId":$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID
    }
]'
```

Three items is required to this API.

```
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_ID
$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID
$VIEW_USER_ID
```

### This is demo steps

I am using Keycloak `v18.0.2`, `curl` ,`jq` and `git bash terminal` at `Windows 10`

(It will be no problem in linux too)

All captured image will be following after `curl` command as a result.

Step 3 & 7 are key steps

[image]

I will demo all of API call by `curl`

#### #1 Set {credential, client name, realm name}

```
MASTER_USERNAME=admin
MASTER_PASSWORD=admin
REALM_NAME=my-realm
CLIENT_NAME=demo
echo '$MASTER_USERNAME = '$MASTER_USERNAME
echo 'MASTER_PASSWORD = '$MASTER_PASSWORD
echo 'REALM_NAME = '$REALM_NAME
echo 'CLIENT_NAME= '$CLIENT_NAME
```

[image]

#### #2 Get master token

more detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

```
MASTER_TOKEN_URL=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration' | jq -r '.token_endpoint')
echo $MASTER_TOKEN_URL
```

[image]

```
MASTER_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "$MASTER_TOKEN_URL" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'username='$MASTER_USERNAME \
--data-urlencode 'password='$MASTER_PASSWORD \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' | jq -r '.access_token')
echo 'MASTER_TOKEN = '$MASTER_TOKEN
```

[image]

#### #3 Create client

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/clients' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$MASTER_TOKEN \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "clientId":"'$CLIENT_NAME'",
    "enabled":true,
    "consentRequired": false,
    "attributes":{},
    "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
    "protocol":"openid-connect",
    "publicClient":false,
    "authorizationServicesEnabled": true,
    "clientAuthenticatorType":"client-secret",
    "redirectUris":["http://localhost:8180/demo"]
}'
```

[image]

#### #4 Get {service-account-user-id}

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_ID=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/users/?username=service-account-'$CLIENT_NAME \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$MASTER_TOKEN | jq -r .[0].id)
echo 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_ID = '$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_ID
```

[image]

#### #5 Get {realm-management-client-id}

```
REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/clients' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$MASTER_TOKEN | jq -r '. | map(select(.clientId == "realm-management")) | .[0].id')
echo 'REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID = '$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID
```

[image]

#### #6 Get {view_user_role_id}

```
VIEW_USERS_ID=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/clients/'$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID'/roles' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$MASTER_TOKEN | jq -r '. | map(select(.name == "view-users")) | .[0].id')
echo 'VIEW_USERS_ID = '$VIEW_USERS_ID
```

[image]

#### #7 Assign `view-users` role to client

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/users/'$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_ID'/role-mappings/clients/'$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$MASTER_TOKEN \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[
    {
        "id":"'$VIEW_USERS_ID'",
        "name":"view-users",
        "description":"${role_view-users}",
        "composite":true,
        "clientRole":true,
        "containerId":"'$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID'"
    }
]'
```

[image]

#### #8 confirm it

Finally, you can confirm it by curl or UI

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/users/'$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_ID'/role-mappings/clients/'$REALM_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$MASTER_TOKEN | jq --indent 4
```

[image]

[image]