# Keycloak REST API > Is it possible to update user session data using admin REST API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I would like to update an attribute of the user session using Keycloak admin REST API, it seems not feasible. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the user's attribute in the session by admin API.

Demo

#### Prepaire

#1 Using Keycloak version 21.0.0

[image]

#2 Add `my-realm` realm

[image]

#3 Add two users at `my-realm` realm

[image]

#4 Login `user` to enter session for her

[image]

#### Steps

[image]

#1 Get `master's` access token by Postman

Detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

**Note** Make a good enough time the `Access Token Lifespan` of master token. The default is 1 minute is not enough to demo

[image]

#2 Get session id by the client session statics API

```
GET http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/client-session-stats
```

[image]

#3 Get user list in session

```bash
GET http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/[session uuid]/user-sessions
```

[image]

#4 Get user information with attributes

```
GET http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/users/[user uuid]
```

[image]

[image]

#5 Update his attribute

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/users/[user uuid]
```

Body of PUT

```
{
    "id": "[user uuid]",
    "username": "user name",
    "attributes": {
        "key1": [
            "value2"
        ],
        "key2": [
            "New Value"
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer. I want to update the attributes of the user sessions, not the user attributes :).

Comment: Can show the real example?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the latest admin rest api docs it does seem possible.

Per this link https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/#_users_resource you can make this api call to update a user:

**Update the user**
[image]

Notice the **Body** parameter using a `UserRepresentation` object. When you go to that link https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/#_userrepresentation you can see that it contains an optional field for `attributes`:
[image]