# Keycloak: getting list of client roles

Tags: keycloak

Using keycloak 19. I need to implement in bash script functionality that is done by UI as following:
Realm / client scopes / {name} / 'Assign role' button, button 'Filter by clients' listbox {name optional} (and then select role by name and assign).

I see that 'filter by clients' sends request:

```
auth/admin/realms/abcde/admin-ui-available-roles/clientScopes/63e6d249-27a7-4d52-a916-9283190b3d08
```

But in documentation, at least new one, there is no such API https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/23.0.5/rest-api/index.html

The question is: how to get such this 'client roles' list via official API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign role to scope REST API

```
POST ${keycloakUrl}/admin/realms/${realm}/client-scopes/${scope.uuid}/scope-mappings/clients/${client.uuid}
```

In Body as JSON array

```json
[
   {
        id: ${matchedRole.clientId},
        name: ${matchedRole.role},
        description: ${matchedRole.description}
    }
]
```

Example

[image]

##### Full demo code by Node.js

Save as `assign-roles.js`

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const keycloakUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/auth';
const realm = 'abcde';
const username = 'admin';
const password = 'admin';
const clientId = 'admin-cli';
const myCustomScope = 'admin-ui-available-roles';

function compareByField(field) {
  return function (a, b) {
    if (a[field] < b[field]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a[field] > b[field]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
}

async function getKeycloakToken() {
  const tokenEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`;
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('grant_type', 'password');
  params.append('client_id', clientId);
  params.append('username', username);
  params.append('password', password);

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, params);
    return response.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting Keycloak token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function getClientScopes(token) {
  const clientScopesEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}/admin/realms/${realm}/client-scopes`;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(clientScopesEndpoint, {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting client scopes:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function getRolesByScope(token, scope) {
  // http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/abcde/admin-ui-available-roles/clientScopes/b7ca523a-a33a-475e-8180-773b390226a2
  const cusomnScopeScopesEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}/admin/realms/${realm}/${scope.name}/clientScopes/${scope.id}?first=0&max=50`;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(cusomnScopeScopesEndpoint, {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting client scopes:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function processRole(token, sortedRoles, roleName, clientName, customScope) {
  const matchedRole = sortedRoles.find(role => role.role === roleName && role.client === clientName);

  if (matchedRole) {
    const scope = { uuid: customScope.id };
    const client = { uuid: matchedRole.clientId };
    const roleDataArray = [
      {
        id: matchedRole.clientId,
        name: matchedRole.role,
        description: matchedRole.description
      }
    ];
    return await setCustomScopeRole(token, scope, client, roleDataArray);
  } else {
    console.log('No matching roles found');
    return null;
  }
}

async function setCustomScopeRole(token, scope, client, roleDataArray) {
  const url = `${keycloakUrl}/admin/realms/${realm}/client-scopes/${scope.uuid}/scope-mappings/clients/${client.uuid}`;

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, roleDataArray, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    if (response.status === 204) {
      return 'Assign role is successful';
    } else {
      return response.data; // Handle other responses as needed
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in setCustomScopeRole:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function main() {
  try {
    const token = await getKeycloakToken();

    const clientScopes = await getClientScopes(token);

    const customScope = clientScopes.filter((scope) => scope.name == myCustomScope)[0];
    console.log('Client Scopes:', JSON.stringify(customScope, null, 4));

    const roles = await getRolesByScope(token, customScope);

    const sortedRoles = roles.sort(compareByField('role'));
    console.log('${customScope.name} Scopes:', JSON.stringify(sortedRoles, null, 4));

    // assign Role to custom scope with role name and client name
    let roleName = 'create-client';
    let clientName = 'realm-management';
    let result = await processRole(token, sortedRoles, roleName, clientName, customScope);
    console.log(`To assign ${roleName} role, ${clientName} client to ${customScope.name} result:`, result);

    roleName = 'view-applications';
    clientName = 'account';

    result = await processRole(token, sortedRoles, roleName, clientName, customScope);
    console.log(`To assign ${roleName} role, ${clientName} client to ${customScope.name} result:`, result);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  }
}

main();
```

##### Before run

[image]

##### Rut it

```
node assign-roles.js
```

[image]

##### After run

[image]

##### Notes Some tips

How to get master token in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

No REST API documentation
You can get the API by reverse engineering in [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference)

Official how to get Client Role API in [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html)

[image]